# How are local variables stored on the call stack (GCC compiler)

Tags: c, gcc, memory, stack

I apologize if this has been asked before, I did try looking at old questions but I am still confused as to how the GCC compiler stores variables on the stack. I understand that it grows downward but what about local variables specifically? Do they just get allocated a block of memory or are they stored in a particular order, I assume it's a particular order but I get confused when I try to visualize it with simple programs:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  char *name = "abc";
  char *p = "123";
  char *q = "hello";
  printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", &q, &p, &name);
}
```

For example this program has three character pointers and I am trying to print out their addresses in a way that would mimic the call stack. When I print them in the order they are declared in the variable with the highest address is the first one printed:

```
0x7fff5b9e2948
0x7fff5b9e2940
0x7fff5b9e293M
```

Making me think that the local variables would get pushed to the stack from last declared to the most recently declared. I guess what I am asking is if this is an accurate visualization of the stack with the order of the elements being added to the stack "q" then "p" then "name"? Or would I print them in opposite order if I wanted to print out something that mimics the order of the stack. Not a homework question or anything just trying to better understand how the stack works before I get into memory allocation.

Comment: `0x7fff5b9e293M` typo? Probably was `0x7fff5b9e2938`.

Comment: You are printing them in reverse order?

Comment: Yes thank you, should have been 0x7fff5b9e2938

Comment: Local variables are not guaranteed to exist, let alone be in order.

Comment: There's no requirement that the stack pointer gets incremented. It be a top-down stack. These could be *registers* if you weren't asking about their addresses.

Comment: @tadman It's not even a requirement to have a stack

Comment: @klutt Exactly. There's a lot of things here that assume a lot about compiler implementation.

Comment: Trying to print in similar order as the stack, like the last variable to be "pushed" would be on the top

Comment: Given that the question is tagged gcc, the assumption of a stack is valid.

Comment: I think the biggest question here is: Why do you wonder this?

Comment: In a non-optimized build you might be able to intuit what's happening here, but all bets are off when it starts optimizing. The exact order of things is usually not relevant, the compiler decides what's best, and what's best may make zero sense unless you're the one who implemented that particular compiler optimization.

Comment: If you are building for debugging with `-Og` or `-O0` then values will be on the stack. Otherwise they will only be there if there are not enough registers or if they need to be passed into another function. If that function is visible outside the translation unit and might be replaced by the linker then the "Platform ABI" will be used, which defines the order of use of registers and stack when calling functions. If the function is declared `static` or is otherwise hidden, GCC can inline the call so values are just used, not passed.

Comment: @klutt to understand how the GCC compiler allocates memory and in what order, I know the memory addresses can be different depending on a lot of things but I assumed they follow some sort of order in terms of how they are declared vs stored

Comment: @Jackson Is it just out of curiosity (completely valid reason for asking) or is there some other problem behind? Because I cannot really imagine how to take advantage of such knowledge in real code.

Comment: If you're really curious about this I'd encourage you to learn more about [compiler design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), possibly by building your own and exploring back-ends like [LLVM](http://llvm.org) which can simplify implementation.

Comment: @klutt Yes no underlying question.. would like to know how the compiler I am using allocates memory I think it's important to understand how low level stuff works when possible, even if it doesn't benefit your code

Comment: @tadman Thank you I will check that out, and maybe some more reading on GCC haha

Comment: GCC has a long history and is fully open-source but it also has a reputation for being a bit of a wreck internally. [`clang`](https://clang.llvm.org) has a much cleaner design and bolts on top of LLVM so you may find it easier to understand. Of course there are other compilers out there like [Open Watcom C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcom_C/C%2B%2B).

Comment: @tadman So the idea that they teach in intro CS, that there is a stack, heap, locals get put on the stack, etc., is not always true? Are there some implementations of (say) the C programming language which work completely differently?

Comment: @user56202 There's no strict requirement to have a stack or a heap at all in a C implementation. It's a popular convention, and a good place to start when implementing a compiler, but all that goes out the window when the optimization passes begin. Some things are only ever in registers, are evaluated during the compile phase, or are optimized out entirely.